# Menu scrolls to div WITHOUT animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i got a onepage website which has menu points that scroll to a div on click. This is working so far. I implemented a jquery function that should give the whole thing an animation but somehow it does not work.

Here is the HTML:

```
  <div class="mainmenu">
        <div class="menuwrapper">
            <div class="menulist">
                <ul class="items">
                    <li class="menuitem">
                        <a href="#home">HOME</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menuitem">
                        <a href="#team">TEAM</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menuitem">
                        <a href="#leistungen">LEISTUNGEN</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menuitem">
                        <a href="#know-how">KNOW-HOW</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menuitem">
                        <a href="#contact">KONTAKT</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is the js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('[name="' + $.attr(this, 'href').substr(1) + '"]').offset().top
        }, 500, "swing");
        return false;
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        sliderResize();
    });
});
```

someone has an idea?

Comment: "somehow it does not work" in what way?

Comment: the js animation does not work. it puts me to the right part in the page but without any animation like the headline already said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when clicking on the `<a>` tag, it still does what an `<a>` tag does... bring you to the link (in this case an anchor tag).

To avoid the default link action, you need to add code to prevent it:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // This will stop the default jump to anchor

    // Now you can add your smooth scroll animation
```

Read the [preventDefault() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)  for more information.

Comment: well now it does not scroll anymore and the console tells me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined"

Comment: @BooooomxD that means the code for your animation has an error in it. I'll give you a hint: use `scrollTop: $(this.href).offset().top` instead

Comment: well it works now, but it´s weird. I saw the .js i used on another website the exact same way and it worked out. but thank you.

Comment: @BooooomxD Instead of simply copying code from other places, try to understand all of it so you can also solve errors by yourself. It's even better if you try to write it all from scratch instead of copying, since functions found on the internet are often incomplete / incorrect / unoptimised. Ofcourse you can look at existing code and learn from it though ;)

Comment: If your issue is solved feel free to accept an answer to close your question.